# Geodesics in a metric space are locally distance minimizers?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, metric-geometry

I am interested in the concept of geodesic in metric space. In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Metric_geometry) I read

> In metric geometry, a geodesic is a curve which is everywhere **locally a distance minimizer**. More precisely, a curve $γ : I → M$ from an
> interval $I$ of the reals to the metric space $M$ is a geodesic if
> there is a constant $v ≥ 0$ such that for any $t ∈ I$ there is a
> neighborhood $J$ of $t$ in $I$ such that for any $a$, $b ∈ J$ we
> have
>
> $ d(\gamma (a),\gamma (b))=v\left|a-b\right|$.

However, I would have thought that a a curve is **locally a distance minimizer** if for any $t ∈ I$ there is a neighborhood $J$ of $t$ in $I$ such that for any $a$, $b ∈ J$ and any curve $\tilde{\gamma} : I\to M$ we have $$\operatorname{length}_{a,b}\tilde{\gamma}\ge\operatorname{length}_{a,b}\gamma$$ where $$\operatorname{length}_{a,b}(\gamma):=\sup\left\{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}d(\gamma(t_k),\gamma(t_{k+1})),n\ge 1, a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b \right\}.$$

Are these thes same?

Comment: For the equivalence of the two definitions, you should assume that $M$ is a path-metric space, i.e. the distance between two points is the infimum of lengths of paths connecting these points. Without this assumption, you only have an implication between the two definitions, not the equivalence.